# @Html.ActionLink does not redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently doing a simple log-in application which also allows the users to change their passwords. However, my`@Html.ActionLink` does not redirect to the change password page and I think it is because of my settings in my web.config. How do I fix it?

Here are my codes.

**Index.chtml (login page)**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(login => login.Username) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(login => login.Username)<br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(login => login.Password) 
    @Html.PasswordFor(login => login.Password)<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "Index", "ChangePW")
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
@ViewBag.Error
```

**Web.config**

```
  <location>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Resulting HTML code after clicking the `Change Password`:

```
<div>
  <h2>BlueBerry Login</h2>

  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
  <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <h2></h2>

  <form action="/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fChangePW" method="post">
    <label for="Username">User name: </label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name:  field is required."   id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="" />
    <br/>
    <label for="Password">Password: </label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password:  field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    <a href="/ChangePW">Change Password</a>
    <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
      <li style="display:none"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I tried using the `@Html.ActionLink` when I entered the application and it worked. It is really weird...

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the code for the log in controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/
    #region Declarations

    MembershipHelper _mem = new MembershipHelper();
    #endregion

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MasterUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_mem.ValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password)) //successful
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
                user = _mem.LoggedUser;
                Session["loggedUser"] = user;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("",_mem.Status);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User does not exist");
        }
        return View();
    }        
}
```

Comment: What happens, when you click the link? Does the link get rendered? Show the html that gets rendered by `@Html.ActionLink`

Comment: Actually, this is the razor code with the html code. When I click the link, it does not redirect. I'm assuming that it is because of the web.config that blocks everything until there is a successful login. But how is it possible if the user would want to change his/her password in the login page? I've already setup a page for this (`ChangePW`) but it does not redirect there.

Comment: please show the resulting HTML. When rendering the view `@Html.ActionLink` typically becomes something like `<a href="...">...</a>`

Comment: @Jan: Bro, see updated inquiry

Comment: Just my two cents: are you referring perhaps to a "Forgot Password" functionality instead of "Change Password"? I would think a "Change Password" functionality would require a user to be actually logged in to change his password.

Comment: @rikitikitik: No. This is actually one of the requirements for the rewrite in the application. The  user can change his/her password in the login page. So it is not the same as the "Forgot Password" functionality.

Comment: @Musikero31 Ok then. What is the relative URL of the Change password page? You just have to add it to your web.config and allow all users to access.

Comment: @rikitikitik: From the code above, it is `/ChangePW` which is the correct URL. How do you add that to my web.config?

Answer (score 0):

WRONG Answer, see below

In your web.config, this:

```
<location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

makes all URLs in your app/site accessible only by logged in users. Adding this

```
<location path="ChangePW">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

exempts your Change Password page from the previous rule, making it accessible even without a log in.

You can safely put back your `@HtmlActionLink` after this and it would work as intended now.

---

EDIT

Apparently, [MVC routing does not work at all with the authorization stuff in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651417/1111088). As described in that link's answer, just add `[Authorize]` to all the controller actions that you would like to restrict behind a login. Of course, you would have to remove the authorization section denying all users in your web.config.

A less tedious way would probably be to move the ChangePassword action to a new controller and then you can use the authorization in web.config by allowing all users for the new controller.

Comment: I did that already just below the `<location path="Scripts">...</location>` section. But it still does not redirect. I get this URL after clicking the `Change Password` link: `http://localhost:18537/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fChangePW`

Comment: It's set to `<allow users="*"/>`?

Comment: Yes. I already did that. Should there be a correct order, like should this be the first then the last would be the deny all unauthorized users?

Comment: Check my updated inquiry. I'll show the code that I have in the controller. Apparently, I don't know where to put the`[Authorize]` tag. Sorry....

Comment: What about your Index controller? Anyway, just add the `[Authorize]` attribute on top of the action, just like how `[HttpPost]` was added to the second index action. If you already have an attribute placed on an action, just add it on top. Your Login controller's Index actions do not need to have this, by the way.